# RN OneSignal _open Event

Tags: react-native, push-notification, react-navigation, react-native-onesignal

OneSignal on notification open event fires after the home screen got launched then it navigates to the desired screen. I want to detect if the app was launched on pressing the notification prior the home screen get rendered so I can navigate to the Second screen directly and avoid unnecessarily calling of apis.

> - "react-native-onesignal": "^3.9.3"
> - "react-navigation": "^4.0.0"

**code**

```
   const _opened = openResult => {
      const { additionalData, body } = openResult.notification.payload;
     // how to navigate or set the initial screen depending on the payload
   }

    useEffect(() => {

        onesignal.init();
        onesignal.addEventListener('received', _received);
        onesignal.addEventListener('opened', _opened);
        SplashScreen.hide();

      return () => {
        // unsubscriber
        onesignal.removeEventListener('received', _received);
        onesignal.removeEventListener('opened', _opened);
      }
   }, []);
```

**Debug**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### your question is how to navigate or set the initial screen depending on the opened notification payload?

##### 1) - set the `initial screen` depending on the opened notification payload.

according to [class Lifecycle](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#adding-lifecycle-methods-to-a-class) `useEffect` runs after the component output has been rendered, so listener in `useEffect` not listen until the component amounting, and this the reason of logs in home screen shown before logs in `useEffect`, see this explanation.

```js
//this the problem (NavigationContainer called before useEffect).
function App() {
  useEffect(() => {}); //called second.
  return <NavigationContainer>; //called first.
}

//this the solution (useEffect called Before NavigationContainer).
function App() {
  const [ready, setReady] = useState(false);

  //called second.
  useEffect(() => { 
    //listen here
    setReady(true);
    SplashScreen.hide();
  });

  //called first
  //no function or apis run before useEffect here it just view.
  if(!ready) return <></>;// or <LoadingView/>

   //called third.
  return <NavigationContainer>;
}
```

###### your code may be like this.

```js
function App() {
    const [ready, setReady] = useState(false);

    const openedNotificationRef = useRef(null);
    
    const _opened = openResult => {
        openedNotificationRef.current = openResult.notification.payload;
    }

    const getInitialRouteName = () => {
        if (openedNotificationRef.current) {
            return "second"; //or what you want depending on the notification.
        }
        return "home";
    }


    useEffect(() => {
        onesignal.addEventListener('opened', _opened);
        //setTimeout(fn, 0) mean function cannot run until the stack on the main thread is empty.
        //this ensure _opened is executed if app is opened from notification
        setTimeout(() => {
            setReady(true);
        }, 0)
    });


    if(!ready) return <LoadingView/>


    return (
        <NavigationContainer initialRouteName={getInitialRouteName()}>
        </NavigationContainer>
    );

}
```

#### 2) - `navigate` depending on the opened notification payload.

first you need to kown that

> A navigator needs to be rendered to be able to handle actions If you
> try to navigate without rendering a navigator or before the navigator
> finishes mounting, it will throw and crash your app if not handled. So
> you'll need to add an additional check to decide what to do until your
> app mounts.

read [docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigating-without-navigation-prop/)

```js
function App() {

    const navigationRef = React.useRef(null);
    
    const openedNotificationRef = useRef(null);
    
    const _opened = openResult => {
        openedNotificationRef.current = openResult.notification.payload;
        //remove loading screen and start with what you want.
        const routes = [
            {name : 'home'}, //recommended add this to handle navigation go back
            {name : 'orders'}, //recommended add this to handle navigation go back
            {name : 'order', params : {id : payload.id}},
        ]
        navigationRef.current.dispatch(
            CommonActions.reset({
                routes : routes,
                index: routes.length - 1,
            })
        )
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        //don't subscribe to `opened` here
        
        //unsubscribe
        return () => {
            onesignal.removeEventListener('opened', _opened);
        }
    }, []);

    //subscribe to `opened` after navigation is ready to can use navigate
    const onReady = () => {
        onesignal.addEventListener('opened', _opened);
        //setTimeout(fn, 0) mean function cannot run until the stack on the main thread is empty.
        //this ensure _opened is executed if app is opened from notification
        setTimeout(() => {
            if (!openedNotificationRef.current) {
                //remove loading screen and start with home 
                navigationRef.current.dispatch(
                    CommonActions.reset({
                        routes : [{name : 'home'}],
                        index: 0,
                    })
                )
            }
        }, 0)
    };


    return (
        <NavigationContainer
            ref={navigationRef}
            onReady={onReady}
            initialRouteName={"justLoadingScreen"}>
        </NavigationContainer>
    );

}
```

refrences for [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Timeouts_and_intervals#settimeout), [CommonActions](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-actions/).